# How can I add files to an encrypted hdd using the dd command without losing my encryption?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

**PURPOSE: DD files to a LUKS encrypted (blank) hdd from another hdd that is 'not' encrypted.**

I'm under the belief that the following is true: If I dd files from an unencrypted hdd to an (blank) encrypted hdd, that the new unencrypted files (on recipient hdd) will remove the encryption.

I was trying to create partitions after encrypting the hdd, but wasn't able to (using gparted); seemed that once the hdd was encrypted, that was a nogo regardless of whether I opened encryption or not in gparted.

I was trying to see if I could encrypt the underlying hdd, and then put non-encrypted files into the partitions. It was just a thought...

"sudo dd if=/dev/sdx1 bs=16M of=/dev/sdy2"

I don't see how I can dd files (coming from non-encryption) to an encrypted hdd without losing the encryption there, or, dd files to a non-encrypted hdd, and then encrypt those files.

**UPDATE:**

```
Encrypted/destination hdd was encrypted w/ LUKS the following way:
> "sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdx 
> "sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdx diskname"
> "sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/diskname"
> "sudo cryptsetup luksClose diskname"
```

**UPDATE**:

> I mounted both the "if" and "of" devices and ran the following command:

```
"sudo dd if=/dev/sdx1 bs=16M of=/dev/mapper/diskname"
```

The files from a non-encrypted device were transferred. 
I closed the encrypted device and shut the device off. 
I then powered the device back on and opened the encrypted drive. 
The drive was still encrypted.

```
Now I am trying the same thing but NOT mounting either of the devices... will update soon...
```

**UPDATE**: 
Using the same 'dd' command, with the host files/ device being 16GB, and the destination NOT mounted, the host files have been copying to the destination for over an hour and are still not done. It appears that the host files are going to go over every bit of the destination hdd, whereas, when the destination was mounted, it completed the same assigned task in about 20 minutes.

Comment: What you are seeking is very unclear.   (Your title conflicts with your body - files vs partitions) etc.   If you create a partition  and then do a "dd" from old LUKS encrypted to new partition that will copy the encrypted - although you will still need to do some things around mounting it - exactly what depends on your distro and use case.

Comment: @davidgo Thanks. I amended the question.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear why you would choose to DD rather then just copy files, but your belief that using dd will loose the encryption is false.  Here is how and why -

Linux filesystems/disks work in layers - Common layers include (from bottom up, although order can be changed for some items and this list is not by any means exclusive)

```
RAW DISK
Partitions
RAID
Logical Volumes (Physical Volumes, Volume Groups, Logical Volumes)
Encryption
Filesystem
```

(Other layers include FUSE, DRBD, Loopback Filesystems/Files Acting as partitions, ZFS bits NFS mounts to name a few)

When you write information onto a mounted partition, it actually writes its way back through all the abstractions.  Thus when you write a file to the filesystem it is unencrypted, but it passes through the encrypted layer, and then eventually to the disk.   Point is that the encryption is a lower level that the filesystem does not need to be aware of.

Labouring the point a bit more, the distro would often take care of this, but lets take a simple case.  Say I had a partition which I wanted to manually make an encrypted disk available (lets assume there is  partition /dev/sda3) here - It would require something like the the following commands -

1. cryptsetup /dev/sda3 encrypteddisk
2. mount /dev/mapper/encrypteddisk /data

Thus when I write a file to /data the its written to a point on /dev/mapper/encrypteddisk - which is not a real block device, rather its an abstracted block device, which uses /dev/sda3 as its backing - however the kernel (ie the kernel or dm_crypt module called by the kernel) is handling abstraction.  The data written to /dev/sda3 is actually encrypted.  Importantly it does not matter how that data is written - provided its written to or through /dev/mapper/encrypteddisk it will be encrypted on the underlying disk.

You can verify this fairly easily if you have a new disk.  Write (preferably plain text) data to the encrypted disk, then use something like strings /dev/sda3 and you will see random strings which bear no resemblence to the text you wrote.  (You can dd arbitrary text to a file with a command like

```
  echo "Hello World - This is arbitrary Text" | dd of /del.file
```

Comment: Thanks! Ok, so, part of the LUKS encryption was formatting the disk with "sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/diskname". Then another step to close the disk after previous step. FIRST QUESTION: when I do the dd command, are you saying to mount the hdd? I never do. SECOND QUESTION: "lsblk" = "sdb= device name"; "diskname = partition (ie: boo.boo)" ---- what would my sudo dd command be? I tried "sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=16M of=/dev/mapper/boo.boo". THIRD QUESTION: what would my "mount" command be? "sudo mount -o ro,noexec /dev/mapper/boo.boo" ?

Comment: The mkfs.ext4 command had nothing to do with encryption (It formats the partition for a filesystem). I expect there was an earlier command that created /dev/mapper/disk name - that would probably  have been the encryption. WHAT ARE YOU TRYING TO ACHIEVE?  How many partitions are you working with and how did you create /dev/mapper/boo.boo?

Comment: Thanks. This "practice-run" I am trying now only has 1 partition, but the actual disk has 3 or 4. I am trying to achieve: using the dd command to send duplicate copy of files (partition content) from a non-encrypted "device" TO an encrypted hdd, and afterwards, still have encryption of destination hdd intact for all files/hdd.

Comment: As long as you dd to the /dev/mapper/boo.boo (or whatever the luks device is) the data will be encrypted.  Why would you not simply mount both partitions and to a cp of the contents though?

Comment: at davidgo Thanks. I have deleted docs that I need to try to get back so I am using dd to make a duplicate in case there is a problem with the original hdd after I try recovery software. I had been emphatically told not to mount the devices when using dd, for whatever reason, unbeknownst to me. I did mount the destination hdd this time as during my prx run, it seemed to run much, much faster. Can mounting while using dd damage anything or prevent proper duplication? "As long as you dd to the /dev/mapper/boo.boo (or whatever the luks device is) the data will be encrypted" = I agree.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah.  If you are doing data recovery you should ideally not have the data you are trying to recover mounted because (a) any writes can cause data which is marked for deletion but not actually deleted to be overwritten and (b) because open filesystems will not be in a clean state if snapshotted, and there may be "holes" in files where data is in an inconsistent state because it was in the process of being written.   Having luks open the mapper volume does not mean it is mounted as far as the OS is concerned.

Comment: at davidgo. Thanks. I wish I had known that sooner :) For starters, I mounted the "destination", the empty hdd "dev/mapper...". It seems as though your (potentially problematic) comments are referring to mounting the "host hdd", yes? If for some reason I did mount the host files before dd'g them over previously, which may have occurred, would good recovery software like 'photorec' be able to recover what was deleted in the dd process? Is there any way to tell if that took place? This may definitely have happened, me "originally" mounting the host files/ hdd. Thanks.

Comment: .... for clarification: "If I mounted the 'host hdd', and the worst case scenario above did occur, would that make the original host hdd, AND the new destination hdd (after it receives the duplicate data/infrastructure) BOTH possibly ruined as far as data recovery?" Thx.

Comment: It would not ruin them, but it could potentially very slightly reduce the amount of recoverable data - mainly around files which are written during the HDD snapshotting. I'm not clear though why you are using an encrypted disk for recovery - this makes an already tricky process harder

Comment: at davidgo. Thanks. Encrypted disk being used simply to keep everything locked up in case anyone got their hands on it. Sounds like you are saying if the disk is encrypted, even after i have to decrypt it to get access, that the deleted files i want to recover will be harder to recover? Though, this is just the backup, not the original, which could have been mounted previously. There are many other files besides the recovery files. The recovery-type files are on their own 1TB partition; other files on other partitions. I lost 50GB worth of important .doc files I need to get back, yes 50GB! thx

Comment: ...... is it ok to mount the destination hdd (which is either empty or host files are going to an emtpy partition)? Thanks.

Comment: ... the reason I ask is because if mounting the empty destination hdd can cause the loss of even a few docs/ data, then I need to redo the whole dd process from scratch. thx.

Comment: From the questions you are asking you really need to keep it as simple as you can. Use gnu ddrescue and a new target drive of a larger size then the original to bit copy the data - then, once recovery is complete you can overwrite the drive using shred -n1 and if that's not enough take an angle grinder to it afterwards.

Comment: I'm not sure what the negative issue is with asking if it is ok to mount the encrypted, but empty 'destination hdd'...?

Comment: Apologies for this comment - you appear to lack understanding and skill working with block devices. Data recovery is hard even when you know what you are doing. Abstracting block devices further then you have to (ie encryption layer) - makes data loss more likely. Also you appear to be creative rather then precise - your question (and understanding?) is vaguely worded and I am not at all confident I understand minor but vital details of what you are asking and I'm pretty sure you dont either.

Comment: at davidgo I do lack understanding and skill working with block devices, very much so, and I like to understand things very thoroughly, hence all the questions. No offense, but that is the whole point as to why I am here asking questions - to learn this stuff, use it successfully, and then be able to teach others. I also agree that my questions are more creative than precise. I need a thorough understanding to be precise, though either way, it's a path to learning. I appreciate the help with volunteering your time to answer my, and other people's, questions, truly.